# How to retrieve .txt file contents from a url in data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get contents from the url of column SECFNAME. [Eg.] https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt

This is code I am trying but not getting the relevant output.

```
for url in d['SECFNAME']:
    request=urllib.request.Request(url,None)
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    for line in file:
        decoded_line = line.decode("utf-8")           
        print(decoded_line)
```

I am getting error `HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

I want a new column "CONTENTS" having contents of url from column "SECFNAME" in the same dataframe.

Comment: do you want the entire text from the url?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the whole text:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt"   
text = urlopen(url).read()
print(text)
```

This generates:

```
 b'-----BEGIN PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE-----\nProc-Type: 2001,MIC-CLEAR\nOriginator-Name: webmaster@www.sec.gov\nOriginator-Key-Asymmetric:\n MFgwCgYEVQgBAQICAf8DSgAwRwJAW2sNKK9AVtBzYZmr6aGjlWyK3XmZv3dTINen\n TWSM7vrzLADbmYQaionwg5sDW3P6oaM5D3tdezXMm7z1T+B+twIDAQAB\nMIC-Info: RSA-MD5,RSA,\n EvPdKfnjzBIjWkEk2RgNCk1/52qXomHpN+LDwL/XTT/XBuAzk70AYYrsxlQbyiqr\n V5559QRyTgPe9PfVt0db9Q==\n\n<SEC-DOCUMENT>0000950170-98-000413.txt : 19980309\n<SEC-HEADER>0000950170-98-000413.hdr.sgml : 19980309\nACCESSION NUMBER:\t\t0000950170-98-000413\nCONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:\t10-K405\nPUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:\t\t21\nCONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT:\t19971228\nFILED AS OF DATE:\t\t19980306\nSROS:\t\t\tNYSE\n\nFILER:\n\n\tCOMPANY DATA:\t\n\t\tCOMPANY CONFORMED NAME:\t\t\tSUNBEAM CORP/FL/\n\t\tCENTRAL INDEX KEY:\t\t\t0000003662\n\t\tSTANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION:\tELECTRIC HOUSEWARES & FANS [3634]\n\t\tIRS NUMBER:\t\t\t\t25163826......
```

You can post-process is the way you please :)